# Hebrew words causes strange errors with ConTeXt IV / LuaTeX

Tags: errors, luatex, context, hebrew

I am experiencing strange problems with ConTeXt IV / LuaTeX. I have some hebrew words which continues to throw following errors: `error: /usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/font-otn.lua:1809: attempt to index local 'chainlookup' (a nil value)` My tools are from Adam Reviczky's Ubuntu PPAs (links can be found [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Ubuntu_installation)) and I just updated them to make sure I have the newest set.

Here is my test file. Cardo font is available from [here](http://scholarsfonts.net/cardofnt.html). Unfortunately the link for 0.99 version was dead so there may be different errors with newer version. I also tried with Ezra SIL font which is available for Ubuntu as `ttf-sil-ezra` package and actually got more errors. With older standalone installation of ConTeXt IV this works.

Any advice?

```
\definefontfeature[hebrew][arabic][script=hebr]
\definefont[hebrew][name:cardo*hebrew]
\starttext
\textdir TRT
\hebrew

סוּסַ֫יִם   % This causes error.
סוּסַ֫יִ    % If I remove one character it works again. (Error with Ezra SIL)
ם   % However that character by itself does not cause error.

סוּסָתַ֫יִם % This causes error.
סוּסָתַ֫יִ  % If I remove one character it works again. (Error with Ezra SIL)
ם   % However that character by itself does not cause error.

סוּסָֽתְךָ  % This causes error.
סוּסָתְךָ   % If I remove one character it works again.
ֽ   % However that character by itself does not cause error.

\stoptext
```

Comment: ConTeXt bug, report it to the developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got confirmation from the developer few days ago that this is indeed a bug. Today I upgraded my tools and problem is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I've had moderate success with Hebrew in ConTeXt (MkIV) using the ttf-sil-ezra package.  Let me know if the following works for you.

```
\definefontfeature[hebrew][arabic][script=hebr]
\definefont[hebrew][name:ezrasil]

\starttext

Here is some text.

\textdir TRT 
\hebrew

בָּיִת שֶל אָבִי

There was some text.

\textdir TLT

Whoops, there was some text.

\textdir TRT
\hebrew
\hebrewAlef \hebrewBet  \hebrewGimel 

\stoptext
```